# Why directly use dir() in all(...) always return False in python?

Tags: python

I want to know if multiple modules are imported, and have tried the following 3 ways. But I found their result are different. I wonder why directly using `dir()` in `all(...)` leads to incorrect result?

```py
import re, os

# Approach 1
all(k in dir() for k in ('re', 'os'))  # False


# Approach 2
're' in dir() and 'os' in dir()  # True


# Approach 3
list = dir()
all(k in list for k in ['re', 'os'])  # True
```

Comment: `dir()` gets you a list of **local** names in the **current scope**. The generator introduces a new scope where `re` and `os` are not local names. Therefore you don't see them..

Comment: Another note  - don't use bulit-in `list` to be your variable next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`dir()` without arguments depends on the current scope](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#dir):

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope.

Inside the generator expression the scope changes:

```py
>>> list(dir() for _ in ("re", "os"))
[['.0', '_'], ['.0', '_']]
```

This is [also true for list, set, and dict comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries):

> aside from the iterable expression in the leftmost `for` clause, the comprehension is executed in a separate implicitly nested scope. This ensures that names assigned to in the target list don't "leak" into the enclosing scope.